# Athena - grab the latest file in bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I'm new to Athena and S3 in general. We have setup Athena to access S3 buckets attached to databases each holding the same table per day of data.
Such as:

```
database-name - "sales"
tables: ["19.02.2019", "18.02.2019",..."01.02.2019"]
```

To query the table I need to run the following as an example:

```
SELECT 
a.creation_date,
a.number,
pa.customer_number,
a.customer_type,
a.name,
a.city,
a.country,
a.type,
a.business,
b.industry,
cu.group,
cu.closing_date,
cu.interest_flag,
FROM 
    (SELECT a.creation_date,
     a.type,
     a.number,
     a.customer_type,
     a.business,
     a.id,
     b.industry,
     customer.id,
     concat (p.first_name, ' ' ,p.last_name) AS name, p.address, p.country
    FROM "accounts"."2019_02_19_01_32_18" AS a
    LEFT JOIN "customers"."2019_02_19_02_31_03" AS c
        ON a.id=c.id
    LEFT JOIN "people"."2019_02_19_06_05_10" AS p
        ON c.person_id=p.id
    LEFT JOIN "strategic_partners"."2019_02_18_05_57_59" AS par
        ON par.uid=p.strapartner_uid
    WHERE a.number is NOT null  and a.customer_type = (1)

    UNION

    SELECT a.creation_date,
    a.type,
    a.number,
    a.customer_type,
    a.business_name,
    a.id,
    b.industry,
    customer.id,
    concat (p.first_name, ' ',p.last_name) AS name, p.address, p.country
    FROM "accounts"."2019_02_19_01_32_18" AS a
    LEFT JOIN "customers"."2019_02_19_02_31_03" AS c
        ON a.id=c.id
    LEFT JOIN "people"."2019_02_19_06_05_10" AS p
        ON c.person_id=p.id
    LEFT JOIN "strategic_partners"."2019_02_18_05_57_59" AS par
        ON par.uid=p.strapartner_uid
    WHERE a.number is NOT null and a.customer_type IN (4,8)
    ) AS a

    LEFT JOIN "progressive_accounts"."2019_02_18_18_15_28" AS pa
     ON pa.credit_number = a.credit_number
    LEFT JOIN "progressive_customer"."2019_02_18_18_15_01" AS cu
     ON pa.prog_number=cu.prog_number
     WHERE a.creation_date>='2018-10-01' AND a.creation_date<='2018-12-31'
     ORDER BY a.creation_date desc, a.business_name asc
```

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to dynamically query the latest available table ? Is it possible to use a function within the query or some alternate solution?

The follow-up question is why can I not use CREATE VIEW for this query. 
I get an error:
Your query has the following error(s):

```
Access denied when writing to location: s3://dp-jupyterlabXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/notebooks/<username>/athena/Unsaved/2019/02/25/<unique reference id>.txt

This query ran against the "database name" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx.
```

When I run a SELECT statement the query is successful and results are generated as expected.

I cannot figure out why the error is returned - in an attempt to check if it is a permission issue I've added to my role the following policies:

```
- glue access to the bucket

- all glue policies to the user
```

I also cannot figure out why Athena is trying to create the VIEW on the database that is selected on right side drop down menu of Athena rather than on a 'public' database (such as with PostgreSQL or similar).

Any guidance would be great!

Comment: You have a very, very complex query that you are trying to create as a VIEW. This would stress most databases! I would suggest you start simple, then work your way up. Start by creating a VIEW that is simple and works (eg just SELECT * from one table). Then, try it on one half of the UNION, etc. You could also try pulling out some of the JOINs from the inner SELECT and put them on the outer-select. It's looking like a great candidate for ETL to create a new table for simple querying rather than having to run that complex query every time. That is quite common with Data Warehousing techniques.

Comment: Thanks for the information - I actually already have a VIEW to simply that query - I was hoping to create that first as per your suggestion but I cannot create even a simple VIEW. I get the same error while trying to create a view using only a simple SELECT statement on one table. Same exact error which I begin to understand why it is being generated.

Comment: In Amazon Athena, if you click the **Settings** link, you can define where to store query results. It is likely that it is currently configured to a non-existent bucket, or the user/Athena does not have permission to write to the given bucket. See: [Query Results - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - i've defined the location of the bucket. Therefore I can save the results of SELECT style queries but not create VIEWS, really strange behaviour.

Comment: Is the error still the same as the above?

Comment: yes - same exact error.

Comment: So, any idea where is it getting the name of the storage location (`dp-jupyterlabXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/notebooks/<username>/`)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - we did a deep dive and exploring - seems that issue is related to: IP restrictions on the bucket to which the results are written to.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a sub-query to return a table name for use in a query.

Instead, you could use `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` each day to make a view point to the 'latest' table. Then, just query the view.

You probably have some daily task that is creating each of those tables, so have it also update the View.

Comment: When I attempt to create a VIEW using the standard syntax, I run into the following error: 

Access denied when writing to location: s3://paht/path/path/path/<id>.txt

This query ran against the "database" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support...  Couldn't find any reference to that error yet and I'm not sure which service might need to be re-configured in order to add those permission to my role. Any ideas here?

Comment: If you remove the `CREATE VIEW` part and just run it as a `SELECT` statement, does it work? Can you edit your question to show the statement that fails?